# When using variant but error-invoke, could errors happens in compiling time instead of bad_variant_access in running time

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

If I have a map like

```
const std::map<int, std::variant<int, std::string>> m ={{1,1},{2,"asd"}};
```

But if i invoke `std::get<string>(m[1])` by mistake instead of `std::get<int>(m[1])`, it will raise bad_variant_access.
But it is just a typo of codes, so could it be detected by IDE, or some form of `static_assert` could work because `m` is a constant(or what if `m` is not a constant) , or raise only compile errors?

Comment: "*it is just a typo of codes*" How would the compiler know that? It has no idea what `m[1]` will return. That's not compile-time code, and `map` isn't a `constexpr` class.

Comment: btw, your last question was about similar topic, already there one could get the impression of a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), that there is some motivation that you are not telling us about. That you are facing some problem that has a nicer solution than a map of variants. Don't get me wrong, this quesiton here is completely ok, but it could be that we can help you much better with your actual problem if you tell us about it.

Comment: It’s a matter of how powerful a static analysis the compiler can do.

Comment: ...and I see you have edited the other question, though that qeustion already had answers. Answers that adress the question as it was before. What I actually wanted to suggest is to open a new question where you explain the acutal problem. The two questions you asked are about a map of variants, ok, the other question can be something else (and "I tried a map of variants" with a link to existing questions can be a side remark). Just my suggestion

Answer (score 3):

If it is always constant, you don't need a map. You can dispatch that at compile time:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int i>
constexpr auto m() 
{
    if constexpr (i == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else if constexpr (i == 2) {
        return "hello";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << m<1>() << '\n';
    std::cout << m<2>() << '\n';
}
```

Or, just use a tuple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    std::tuple tuple { 1, "hello world" };
    std::cout << std::get<0>(tuple) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::get<1>(tuple) << '\n';
}
```